# Grey out menustrip items when certain forms are open/active/focused

Tags: c#, .net, menustrip

On my parent form i have a menustrip. I disabled `(Enabled=false)` some options by default. However i cannot access the menu from the child where i need to enable these items.

I tried a lot of variations like this in the child form constructor:

> ```
> string[] visibleItems = new[] { "Export", "Import" };
> foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in MdiParent.MainMenuStrip.Items) //base.MainMenuStrip.Items, MainMenuStrip.Items, base.Menu.MdiListItem.MenuItems won't work either.
> {
>     if (visibleItems.Contains(item.Name)) item.Enabled = true;
> }
> ```

I get a null pointer error and i cannot seem to find access to the menu i created.

Anyway, if i get it working like this i imagine that i have to disable the items again when the window loses focus or gets closed. So what is a proper method to access the item properties when different forms get opened/closed focused/unfocused?

Comment: I would make some kind of button controller class.  Pass in your button list and the form and let the controller handle everything.

Comment: @Dan-o Could you elaborate some more? Point me in the right direction? I am fairly new to winform and completely new to MDI.

Comment: Well, why don't you try something, and if you still need help post a new question.

Comment: Do i need something like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

And why post another question? The question as it stands is the problem, maybe with a wrong approach of me. Take a read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments?cb=1

Comment: No.  You do not need System.Winforms.Control.  You need to write a class that will act as a controller.  It is a class that will *control* the buttons.  This is basic OOP 101.  Design a class that you pass in a list of menu item buttons and a form and wire up the form events to control the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, just in case someone faces the same issue.
You can try to change the modifiers of the control to Public, and check it out again.